# (Drupal 6) $theme_key returning no value

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view

I am trying to set up a Drupal 6 node to load blocks dynamically depending on the selected theme. I figured that I could use $theme_key to determine the name of the theme, and work from there. The weird thing is that if I have several checks on a page, the first one will return an empty value for $theme_key, but subsequent checks will work as expected.

For instance:

```
<?php
print "Theme: ". $theme_key;
if($theme_key =="foo"){
 $viewName = 'theView';
 $display_id = 'block_1';
 print views_embed_view($viewName, $display_id);
}
else {
 $viewName = 'theOtherView';
 $display_id = 'block_1';
 print views_embed_view($viewName, $display_id);
}
?>
```

If I have the above in the node multiple times with theme "foo" active (for testing purposes) - the first time will return a blank value for $theme_key, and display theOtherView, but the second time it will show Theme: foo and will display theView. All subsequent calls to $theme_key will be correct as well.

Any calls to $theme_key prior to the first block will return blank values.

I am declaring

```
<?php global $theme_key; ?>
```

at the beginning of the node content. (Before all of the conditional blocks...)

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to check the current theme?

Comment: Have you tried just `$theme` ? its a global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking at the [init_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/init_theme/6) function the globals `$theme` and `$theme_key` contain exactly the same values so you could try using `$theme` (as yvan suggested), but as they contain the same data and are both globals set in the same function I'm not sure it would make any difference.

Is this code in a template file? If so you could be suffering from the age old Drupal theming problem whereby some variables aren't available when the template is built. You could try adding a `hook_preprocess_node()` function in a module/theme to set up the variable and pass it to your template file. Something like this:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  global $theme_key;
  $vars['current_theme_key'] = $theme_key;
}
```

And then in your template file you'll have access to the variable `$current_theme_key`, which should then have the right variable in it.

Hope that helps, I've come across these sort of problems with Drupal before and they're a nightmare to debug.

**Edit to add more helpful function:**

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $node = $vars['node'];

  if ($node->type == 'my_type') {
    global $theme_key;

    $view_name = $theme_key == 'foo' ? 'theView' : 'theOtherView';
    $display_id = 'block_1';

    $vars['my_custom_view'] = views_embed_view($view_name, $display_id);
  }
}
```

Then in your node.tpl.php or node-type.tpl.php file you can use code like this:

```
if (isset($my_custom_view)): 
  echo $my_custom_view; 
endif;
```

By constructing the variables in a preprocess function you shouldn't have any problems with the global `$theme_key` not being available any more.

Bear in mind you could also implement this in your theme (in the template.php file) by changing the function name to MYTHEME_preprocess_node.

Make sure you clear your Drupal cache once you've implemented the function (wherever you decide to put it) so the system will pick up the changes.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This code was actually directly in body copy of a node (yes, php was enabled on the node) - what I ended up doing for the time being was to create a completely empty block and place it first - that seems to have forced $theme_key to populate. Seems like a pretty gross hack though. (FWIW, @yvan I did try $theme also, same behavior)

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, it's generally considered bad practice to use the PHP filter for node content - I think specifically because of the scope that the code is executed in

Comment: Thanks Clive - what would you consider a better practice? My goal is to embed a view into a node conditionally depending on the theme selected (I have different markup for my mobile/desktop themes) - or is the whole goal faulty? Should I be building the view itself with conditional/multi-function markup?

Comment: You're goal definitely isn't faulty, the annoying/wonderful thing about Drupal is there are many ways to skin a cat! Personally I'd move the view rendering logic into a preprocess function like in the 1st example above; I'll update the code to show you what I mean

Comment: I have a related question - one of my other views is set up as a page, but I would like to add this type of conditional view selection to it as well. Can I put a view_embed like yours above into a tpl.php for a view that's already a page? (Or should I rebuild both views to be blocks? (really don't want to because the original view was built by an outside contractor and I am loathe to disrupt it)

Comment: Sorry, one more question - you are using syntax I'm not familiar with and I just want to make sure I understand it. When you say $view_name = $theme_key == 'foo' ? 'theView' : 'theOtherView'; do you mean If theme_key == foo then view_name=theView, else view_name=theOtherView?

Comment: You're spot on with the syntax question, it's using the [PHP ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), very useful for writing more readable/compact code. The other one's a bit more tricky, I think you'd be looking at implementing a preprocess function for a view with a corresponding template file. Rather than try to go through the whole process in this comment I'd suggest looking at [Preprocessors for each view](http://drupal.org/node/303586) which has a lot of helpful information.